# Absolute Value of the Differences In Two (2) Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am Looking to calculate the sum of the absolute values of the differences in two (2) named ranges using a VBA function. The formula below calculates the sum of the differences in the two (2) ranges, but I am having difficulty getting the absolute value of the sum of the differences in the ranges.

I have tried any number of combinations of `ABS` or even the Square Root of the Squares without luck. The result gives an error in the user defined function.

```
'Volatility Calculation

Rng0 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N0Addr)) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N1Addr))
```

`Rng0` is a value to be used in the denominator of a fraction calculating a smoothing factor. The output above for `Rng0` provides the correct value for the sum of the differences but I am looking for the absolute value of the sum of differences in a VBA formula. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the entire function.  Named ranges in the worksheet would be surrounded by quotes, `Range("N1Addr")`.  Are you setting these ranges within the function?

Comment: I agree that the proper range entry is "in quotes," but the formula does not work for some reason. The entry as written yields the correct result.  'TEST Function for nKAMAv
Function nTEST(Price, nPer, mPer, N)

'Variables
Fast = 2 / (nPer + 1)
Slow = 2 / (mPer + 1)

N0Addr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Price.Offset(-N, 0).Address & ":" & Price.Address)
N1Addr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Price.Offset(-(N + 1), 0).Address & ":" & (Price.Offset(-1, 0).Address))

'Change Formula (Abs(Y - Yn))
E = Abs(Price - Price.Offset(-N, 0))

Comment: The rest of the formula is as follows:

Comment: R = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N0Addr)) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N1Addr))

'EFFICIENCY RATIO
ER = E / R

Smooth = (ER * (Fast - Slow) + Slow) ^ 2


Hopefully this helps

Comment: BTW:  The following formula works directly in Excel:

=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(I26:I36-I25:I35)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to sum the range and then calculate the absolute value to get the difference then it would look like this:

```
Rng0 = Abs(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N0Addr))) - Abs(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N1Addr)))
```

But if you are trying to get the absolute value of each cell in the range, sum it, then get the difference you would have to iterate over the range to get the sum of the abs values using a loop then subtract the two.

Edit: Here is a simple loop that does what your formula does.  By the way the formula is doing the exact same thing in the background, it is using a loop to calculate the sumproduct.

Simple custom Function:

```
Public Function MyFunction(r1 As Range, r2 As Range)

    For i = 1 To r1.Count
        MyFunction = MyFunction + Abs(r1(i) - r2(i))
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Looking to Sum the absolute value of the differences between each of the corresponding cell pairs in the two ranges.  I can get the sums to work in the formula above but not the absolute value.

Comment: I have been trying to avoid looping iterations since I can enter formulas, both Arrays and straight formulas, that calculate the proper result. I just cannot get the VBA code correct to accomplish it.

Comment: Successfully incorporated this above response from R. Roe on May 14th. It works as very nicely and as advertised. This is to thank everyone who responded. All of the comments and responses were most helpful, and all of your efforts are greatly appreciated. Thank you.